# TS Error when implementing interface Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this weird error, I'm not sure what the reason I'm getting it is..

So I have this interface declared like so,

```
export interface ActivitySelection {
   header: string;
   activities: [
     {
       activityName: string;
       available: boolean;
     }
   ];
}
```

now In one of my components I'm trying to use the interface like so..

```
let activity: ActivitySelection

activity = {
   header: 'TEST 1',
   activities: [
      {
         activityName: 'activity-1',
         available: true
      },
      {
         activityName: 'activity-2',
         available: false
      }
   ]
}
```

but Im getting a TS error that says

`[ts]
Type '{ header: string; activities: [{ activityName: string; available: false; }, { activityName: strin...' is not assignable to type 'ActivitySelection'.
  Types of property 'activities' are incompatible.
    Type '[{ activityName: string; available: false; }, { activityName: string; available: true; }, { activ...' is not assignable to type '[{ activityName: string; available: boolean; }]'.
      Types of property 'length' are incompatible.`

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is because i'm using my interface correctly??

any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your interface, you have specified that `activities` will be an array with a single element being the object you have specified. You need to update your interface to the following:

```
export interface ActivitySelection {
   header: string;
   activities: {
       activityName: string;
       available: boolean;
   }[];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought that might of been the case!! but I wasn't sure how to do this correctly

Answer (score 1):

Even though the above answer provides the answer to your quesiton, you can also create an interface for activity and have the activities as a type of Activity array,

```
export interface ActivitySelection {
   header: string;
   activities: activity[];
}

export interface Activity{
  activityName: string,
  available: boolean
}
```